# How to input text into a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function idloop(i) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Loading " + (i+1) + "/" + IDs.length + " ...";
    if (typeof CCPEVE != 'undefined') CCPEVE.showMarketDetails(IDs[i]);
    if (i + 1 < IDs.length) {
      setTimeout(function() { idloop(i + 1) }, delay)
    }
    else {
      var i = 0
    }
}

<input type="text" id="new" name="new" value="1" />
<a href="javascript:idloop(0);">Start Loop</a><br>
<span ID="status">...</span>
```

I am a javascript newb so would like some help here.

I have the above script that accesses data within a game. I was fiddling with how to input text as the starting value (i, which starts at 0 normally) but could not figure out how.

I pretty much want to be able to loop that script, then stop it (unsure how to add a 'stop' button without reloading page) and then restart it from where I was by typing the number of where I was up to.

Comment: you mean you want to read the input text value inside a function?

Comment: Is the game's source code publicly available?

Comment: Possibly you may try using [setInterval() and clearInterval()](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/setIntervalandclearIntervalmethods.htm)